# Why are indexed ORDER BY queries matching many rows a LOT faster than queries matching only a few?

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.3

Okay so I have the following query:

```
explain analyze SELECT seller_region FROM "products" 
  WHERE "products"."seller_region" = 'Bremen'
    AND "products"."state" = 'active' 
  ORDER BY products.rank DESC, 
    products.score ASC NULLS LAST, 
    GREATEST(products.created_at, products.price_last_updated_at) DESC 
  LIMIT 14 OFFSET 0
```

The query filtering matches around `11.000 rows`. If we look at the query planner, we can see that the query uses the index `index_products_active_for_default_order` and is very fast:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..9767.16 rows=14 width=36) (actual time=1.576..6.711 rows=14 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using index_products_active_for_default_order on products  (cost=0.43..4951034.14 rows=7097 width=36) (actual time=1.576..6.709 rows=14 loops=1)
        Filter: ((seller_region)::text = 'Bremen'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3525
Total runtime: 6.724 ms
```

Now if I replace `'Bremen'` with `'Sachsen'` like so in the query:

```
explain analyze SELECT seller_region FROM "products" 
  WHERE "products"."seller_region" = 'Sachsen'
    AND "products"."state" = 'active' 
  ORDER BY products.rank DESC, 
    products.score ASC NULLS LAST, 
    GREATEST(products.created_at, products.price_last_updated_at) DESC 
  LIMIT 14 OFFSET 0
```

The same query only matches around `70 rows` and is now consistently very very slow, even though it uses the same index in the exact same way:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..1755.00 rows=14 width=36) (actual time=2.498..1831.737 rows=14 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using index_products_active_for_default_order on products  (cost=0.43..4951034.14 rows=39505 width=36) (actual time=2.496..1831.727 rows=14 loops=1)
        Filter: ((seller_region)::text = 'Sachsen'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 963360
Total runtime: 1831.760 ms
```

I don't understand why this happens? I would out of intuition think the the query matching more rows would be slower, but it's the other way around. I Have have tested this with other queries on other columns on my tables as well, and the phenomenon is the same. Two similar queries with the same ordering as the ones above, renders those that matches more rows 100's of times faster than those where the filtering only match a few. Why is this, and how can I avoid this behavior?

PS: I'm using postgres 9.3 and the index is defined as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX index_products_active_for_default_order
  ON products
  USING btree
  (rank DESC, score COLLATE pg_catalog."default", (GREATEST(created_at, price_last_updated_at)) DESC)
  WHERE state::text = 'active'::text;
```

Comment: Note: the actual number of matching rows is 14 in both cases, but the estimates differ. Do you have valid statistics?

Comment: The 14 is because of the limit in each query

Comment: What I find puzzling.  You say Bremen has 11,000 rows.  Why then are rows removed by filter just 3,525 whereas Sachsen has rows removed by filter: 963,360?  How many records are in the table.  Why must Sachsen remove so many more?

Comment: Yes, that is correct; the scan is stopped if 14 tuples have been produced. But in the second case 963360 have to be scanned and rejected by the filter. Maybe adding an extra non-conditional index on {status, region} or vice versa could trigger the collection of statistics for the status-column (IIRC, the precondition for an index is not a candidate for statistics collection. correct me if I'm wrong) BTW what is this `rank DESC, ` doing in the index ?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock There are around 1,6million rows matching the state = 'active'. The seller_region column is a varchar(30) and takes around 20 different values very differently distributed. So this is how it should be

Comment: @joop I don't see how the database can "stop" the scan earlier, since it still needs to order the results as requested, so essentially it would need to know/scan all the same rows, to determine which to put first - or am I misunderstanding something fundamentally?

Comment: `ORDER BY products.rank DESC,` is the index's order, so no sorting is needed. After filtering: just count until 14 are collected and: stop the scans.

Comment: Maybe a (partial) index with seller_region as first member could help. (it might avoid filtering out 900K records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the first 14 matching rows for Bremen are found in the first 3539 index rows, while for Sachsen 963374 rows have to be scanned.

I recommend an index on `(seller_region, rank)`.